# Spring Boot Reactive WebService

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-webflux, reactive

We want to build a rest API to service high request volumes. I'm planning to build it using Spring Reactive(WebFlux) or using Spring Boot Async. We have multiple different clients who will be invoking our service.
Do I need to worry about different clients who will be consuming this service? Meaning if I build the API using Reactive or Async, will all the clients be able to consume this seemlessly?
Meaning if  build a reactive Rest API, will the client using RestTemplate be able to consume or do they need to use WebClient only?

Comment: Yes, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your (not non blocking) clients will still be able to consume a reactive service.